# Category filter with 3 categories

Tags: wordpress, filter

I have a WordPress query and filter with checkboxes by category:

```
if( isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && isset ($_POST['zeitmodell'])  ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['vertragsart']
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['zeitmodell']
        ),
    );

} elseif( !isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && isset ($_POST['zeitmodell'])  ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['zeitmodell']
    );

} elseif( isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && !isset ($_POST['zeitmodell'])  ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['vertragsart']
    );
}
```

This works as it should. On pageload he shows me all results and the user is able to limit the result with the checkboxes.

Now I want to add a third category filter - any idea how to do this? I think it will be way more complex because it is more than if/else.

I tried this but when it comes to the 3rd filter it just shows everything:

```
if( isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && !isset ($_POST['zeitmodell']) && isset ($_POST['fachbereich'])  ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['vertragsart']
    );      
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['fachbereich']
    );      
} elseif( isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && isset ($_POST['zeitmodell']) && !isset ($_POST['fachbereich'])  ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['vertragsart']
    );
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['zeitmodell']
    );
} elseif( isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && !isset ($_POST['zeitmodell']) && isset ($_POST['fachbereich'])  ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['vertragsart']
    );
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['fachbereich']
    );



} elseif( !isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && !isset ($_POST['zeitmodell']) && isset ($_POST['fachbereich'])  ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['fachbereich']
    );
} elseif( isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && !isset ($_POST['zeitmodell']) && !isset ($_POST['fachbereich'])  ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['vertragsart']
    );  
} elseif( !isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && isset ($_POST['zeitmodell']) && !isset ($_POST['fachbereich'])  ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['zeitmodell']
    );


// this won't work
} elseif( isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && isset ($_POST['zeitmodell']) && isset ($_POST['fachbereich'])  ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['vertragsart']
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['zeitmodell']
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['fachbereich']
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems repetive code, I would recommend something like this:

```
// first, set categories
$categories = array('vertragsart', 'zeitmodell', 'third_code');

foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    // if category is checked
    if (isset($_POST[$cat]) {
            // if $cats_array is assigned already, add category array, else, create $cats_array
        if (isset($cats_array)) {
            array_push(
                $cats_array, array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                        'field' => 'id',
                        'terms' => $_POST[$cat]
                )
            );
        } else {
            $cats_array = array(
            array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                        'field' => 'id',
                        'terms' => $_POST[$cat]
                )
            );
        }
    }
}

if (isset($cats_array) && is_array($cats_array)) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = $cats_array;
}
```

EDIT:

better code, will probably work with more than 2:

```
$categories = array('vertragsart', 'zeitmodell', 'third_code');

foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    // if category is checked
    if (isset($_POST[$cat]) {
      if (isset($cats)) {
                    $cats .= ',' $cat;
                } else {
                    $cats = $cat;
                }
    }
}

if (isset($cats)) {
    $args['category_name'] = $cats;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, is by including all possible combinations like so:

```
if( isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && isset ($_POST['zeitmodell']) && isset ($_POST['third_category'])  ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['vertragsart']
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['zeitmodell']
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['third_category']
        ),
    );

} elseif( isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && isset ($_POST['zeitmodell']) && !isset ($_POST['third_category'])   ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['vertragsart']
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['zeitmodell']
        ),
    );

} elseif( isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && !isset ($_POST['zeitmodell']) && isset ($_POST['third_category'])  ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['vertragsart']
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['third_category']
        ),
    );
} elseif( !isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && isset ($_POST['zeitmodell']) && isset ($_POST['third_category'])   ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['zeitmodell']
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['third_category']
        ),
    );

} elseif( isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && !isset ($_POST['zeitmodell']) && !isset ($_POST['third_category'])  ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['vertragsart']
    );
} elseif( !isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && isset ($_POST['zeitmodell']) && !isset ($_POST['third_category'])  ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['zeitmodell']
    );
} elseif( !isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && !isset ($_POST['zeitmodell']) && isset ($_POST['third_category'])  ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['third_category']
    );
}
```

I must admit, it is quite repetitive coding. If it stays 3 categories, the above works fine. Otherwise you could look for a more dynamic approach.

Comment: Hi, yes I tried this, too, but I think `if( isset( $_POST['vertragsart'] ) && isset ($_POST['zeitmodell']) && isset ($_POST['fachbereich'])  ) { ...` leads to just show all.

Comment: And it is not that all posts are in those 3 categories?